# Laravel TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image on windows (but working on server CentOS)

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

http://localhost/imobile/public/apartament-deschide-privat-pdf/3674

The Image exists in the location specified. 
I tried applying:

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
allow_url_include = On;
memory_limit=512M
```

in php.ini but that could not resolve the problem.

I tried both path:

```
storage_path()
public_path()
```

Comment: This is a little short on usable detail. Please remember we are not clarevoyant and we are not looking over your shoulder. Can you add some more details that would be useful to someone that does not have direct contact with your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable rewrite module on your local installation of PHP in order to use .htaccess.
If you're using an app like Xampp, or Wamp you need to edit this file:

```
{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then, uncomment it by removing the "#".

Comment: The module is enabled